# Getting error as 'handleChange is not a function' while selecting date in Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

On selecting specific date in `DatePicker` component, getting error as *'handleChange is not a  function'* as mentioned above. `DatePicker` component is wrapped in `Controller` component of `react-hook-form`. Expected to display date on `DatePicker` input. How could it be resolved? See the code below:

```
<form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="date"
          render={({ handleDateChange, selectedDate, ref }) => (
            <>
              <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                <Grid container justify="space-around">
                  <DatePicker
                    ref={ref}
                    value={selectedDate}
                    onChange={handleDateChange}
                    format={`d  |  ` + `MMMM  |  ` + `yyyy`}
                    disablePast
                    animateYearScrolling
                    margin="normal"
                    style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  />
                </Grid>
              </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>

              <br />
            </>
          )}
          rules={{
            required: "Date is required"
          }}
        />
      </form>
```

Here is the CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-currying-lwtrj

Any suggestion or code changes is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there is no such properties as `handleDateChange` or `selectedDate`, perhaps this is what you mean:

```
render={({ onChange: handleDateChange, value: selectedDate, ref }) => (
```

Secondly, you're using `react-hook-form` v7, the `render` method signature of `Controller` was changed. See the migration guide [here](https://react-hook-form.com/migrate-v6-to-v7/). You need to get the input props from the `field` property, not directly from the render props:

```
render={({ field }) => {
  const {
    onChange: handleDateChange,
    value: selectedDate,
    ref
  } = field;
```

Full working code:

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="date"
  render={({ field }) => {
    const {
      onChange: handleDateChange,
      value: selectedDate,
      ref
    } = field;
    return (
      <>
        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
          <Grid container justify="space-around">
            <DatePicker
              ref={ref}
              value={selectedDate}
              onChange={handleDateChange}
              format={`d  |  ` + `MMMM  |  ` + `yyyy`}
              disablePast
              animateYearScrolling
              margin="normal"
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
            />
          </Grid>
        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>

        <br />
      </>
    );
  }}
  rules={{
    required: "Date is required"
  }}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67200152/getting-error-as-handlechange-is-not-a-function-while-selecting-date-in-materi]